# Evaluate the iterated integral by changing the order of integration?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\int_{0}^1\int_{\sqrt{y}}^1\frac{ye^x}{x^3}dxdy$

$$$$
I have no clue on how to tackle this integral. Can someone help me? Thank you.

This is as far as I got

$$0\le y\leq 1$$
$$\sqrt{y}\leq x\leq1$$

I use algebra to manipulate the order of integration to get this integral. The limits are reversed from the integral up top.
$$\int_{x^2}^1\int_{0}^1\frac{ye^x}{x^3}dxdy$$
I integrate with respect to the new limits and cannot get past this new integral.
$$\int_{0}^1\frac{e^x}{2x^3}-xe^xdx$$
I don't know how to tak this further. Wolfram alpha spits out nonsense.

Comment: Do you understand what "changing the order of integration" means for a double integral? Do you have examples of that prior in your notes and/or text to try to adapt to this situation?

Comment: I added my work.

Comment: The way you changed your integration limits is wrong. Read up more about how to change the limits of integrals in double integrals.

Comment: As a quick consistency check, you shouldn't have an expression with a variable of integration like $x^2$ in the limits of the outer integral. That would mean that the final answer of the double integral would be something like $F(1)-F(x^2)$, but if $x$ is a variable of integration, there should be no $x$ left in the final answer.